# python np.dot outer product works but inner product returns nan, so weird

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[jupyter notebook partial output, please check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CguBb.png)

[image]

I try a lot of method to change the datatype but still not working. Is it a bug for numpy?

Comment: Might be either, but nothing can be said from just a picture.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / input / output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your image. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your array (from pandas) has a `nan` or other value that produces a nan in multiplication.  There may be a `nan` in the first result, but it just doesn't show because it's hidden by the ellipsis.

For a small example:

```
In [550]: x = np.array([[1,2, np.nan,4,5]],dtype=object)
In [551]: np.dot(x.T,x)                     # (n,1)*(1,n)=>(n,n)
Out[551]: 
array([[1, 2, nan, 4, 5],
       [2, 4, nan, 8, 10],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [4, 8, nan, 16, 20],
       [5, 10, nan, 20, 25]], dtype=object)
In [552]: np.dot(x,x.T)                     # (1,n)*(n*1)=>(1,1)
Out[552]: array([[nan]], dtype=object)
```

A pandas dataframe often uses object dtype, and has `nan` to represent unknown or incomplete data.